# CyanogenMod 7 - can I hide the status bar on the lockscreen?

Tags: cyanogenmod, lock-screens, notification-bar

I am using a Google Nexus One and have just flashed CyanogenMod 7 onto it.  I noticed that the lockscreen shows the status bar on it, as shown on the image with this post.

Is there a way to hide the status bar on the lockscreen?  You can see what I am trying to achieve in this case, which is a lockscreen that only displays the wallpaper (CyanogenMod gesture to unlock).  I have been able to hide the sliders as well through the CyanogenMod settings but could not find a way to hide the status bar when the lockscreen is active.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Switch to custom lockscreens. Many provide a way to hide status bar. I use [WidgetLocker Lockscreen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker) which supports this feature.

Comment: My main reason for sticking with CM7 is the gesture based lock screen.  Does WidgetLocker Lockscreen allow for gestures/drawings to unlock?